# Em C, como comparar uma string obtida apartir de strtok com outra string

Tags: c, string

Bom Pessoal, no meu avancos em estudo da linguagem C, estou trabalhando com a manipulacao de arquivos, nada muito complicado, mas cheguei num problema que nao consiguo resolver, e por falta de mais definicao nas buscas e dificil encontrar um problema semelhante e resolvido na internet, entao recorro a voces novamente

Sem enrolar mais, no meu codigo, em teste, peco ao usuario para digitar um nome, entao chamo a funcao LerDados para verificar se esse nome esta disponivel dentro da aplicacao. Se virem no codigo, quando chega na parte para analizar entre "token" e "name" nao acontece nada mesmo sendo valores iguais. De certo que nao sao, usei o debug do CodeBlocks, e dentro de token, em vez de ser por exemplo, apenas "maria", esta aparecendo "maria\n001236", porem quando e chamado printf, aparece corretamente "maria" e nao "maria\n001236" so como exemplo. Porque isso acontece? o que faco para dividir essa string novamente? Desculpem por erros na edicao, pois estou sem pc, usando apenas o smartphone

arquivos users.txt
obs: Usei o & como caracter final para teste por enquanto, porque usando EOF, '-1', -1, sempre dava um loop infinito nao sei o porque.
obs2: o conteudo do arquivo users.txt e o que estiver dentro das chaves
{

/* Registro de usuarios do sistema, tipo csv(comando separado por virgula), aonde temos, id de usuario(para manipulacao do sistema) nome usuario

exemplo:

0001,aislan

*/

#
001234,aislan
001235,maria
001236,joao
001237,silas

&
}

arquivo InterfaceCliente.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


void LerDados(char name[15])
{


    FILE *users;                // cria variável ponteiro para referenciar na 
                                // memoria um tipo de arquivo txt, no caso o
                                // user.txt
    char url[] = { "/sdcard/bd.cafeblue/bd/users.txt" };
    // url q se encontra o arquivo users.txt




    // abrindo o arquivo com tipo de abertura w
    users = fopen(url, "r");

    // testando se o arquivo foi realmente criado
    if (users == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {


        int i = 0;
        char *string;
        int tamVetor = 0;

        string = malloc(sizeof(char **) * tamVetor);
         while ((lido = fgetc(users)) != '&')
        {
            if (lido == '#')
            {

                while ((lido = fgetc(users)) != '&')
                {


                    string[i] = lido;
                    i++;
                    tamVetor++;

                    string = realloc(string, sizeof(char **) * tamVetor);

                }
                break;

            }

        }



        printf("%s", string);



        char *token;


        token = strtok(string, ",");

        while (token != NULL)
        {


            printf("%s\n", token);



            if (strcmp(name, token) == 0)
            {


                printf("Usuario ja cadastradoe!\n");
                break;
            }



            token = strtok(NULL, ",");




        }


    }

    fclose(users);



}




int main()
{

    char user[15];
    printf("Entre com o nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &user);

    LerDados(user);

}
```

Comment: O seu código tem bem mais coisas do que são relevantes ao problema, incluindo funções que não tem instruções, logo deixe apenas o que é relevante ao problema. Aproveite e acerte a parte da informação que está no arquivo, pois não da para perceber ao certo o que realmente tem, já que vejo vários símbolos perdidos como `#`, `&`, `}` e fico sem perceber se fazem parte ou não.

Comment: Isac, editei, ve se consegue entender e me ajudar, aguardo!

Comment: Por que não coloca vírgulas, no arquivo _users.txt_, em todos os campos? Por exemplo,
`#1,Aislan,<quebra de linha>
2,Maria,<quebra>
3,Silva,<quebra>
4,Uchimura,<quebra>
5,Costa,<quebra>
6,Marcelo,<quebra>`

Comment: Obrigado pelo contato Marcelo. O arquivo esta formatado da maneira como voce recomendou.

Comment: Mas o conteudo do arquivo é apenas o `001234,aislan 001235,maria 001236,joao 001237,silas` ? Tem como formatar apenas o que está dentro do arquivo com formatação de código na pergunta ? Utilizando `Ctrl+k` ou o botão `{}` do editor.

Comment: Obrigado pelo contato Marcelo. Fiz da maneira recomenda e realmente deu certo, so coloquei a virgula entre o ultimo campo e a quebra de linha e deu certo. Aproveitando, saberia me dizer o porque do & funcionar no while que verifica quando e o fim do arquivo e o EOF e nem o -1 funcionar?